# computing average in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have data in format

```
1,1.2
2,1.3
and so on..
```

So basically this is id, val combination where id is unique...

I want to calculate the average of all the values..

```
So here.. avg(1.2,1.3)
```

I was going thru the documentation but most of the aggregation function involves grouping by some id.. and then using AVG... but since the id is unique.. how do I group them???
So basically the outcome of this endeavor would be one float..
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP X ALL` should solve your problem :)

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(') AS (f1:int, f2:int);
B = GROUP A ALL;
AV = FOREACH B GENERATE AVG(A.f1);
DUMP AV;
```